# Accessing webcam using python

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, v4l2

Trying to access webcam (video 0) using opencv, python and I get the following error:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
pos_frame = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)

I0626 11:31:59.156796 18887 net.cpp:744] Ignoring source layer silence_rpn_bbox_pred
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: getting property #1 is not supported
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: getting property #1 is not supported -1.0 frames
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: getting property #1 is not supported
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: getting property #7 is not supported
```

Any leads will be appreciated

Comment: What is your OS? Assuming it's Linux, can you make your camera work when you run `gstreamer-configure` or a video capturing app like Cheese?

Comment: Not all the `VideoCapture` backends support all the properties. Looking at [the](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L1618) [source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L1593), it seems that the error message aren't lying.

Comment: Using Ubuntu. I am trying to interface it with Deep Learning algorithm with python script.

Comment: Can you actually get images? It's not like getting frame position is a necessity when you retrieve individual frames from a webcam on demand.

Comment: Just the first frame

Comment: Have you tried other indices ? cv2.VideoCapture(1) for instance

Comment: Thanks . The frame position was giving me the error which I did not really need. I removed it and it is working fine now.